# Displaying long SFTP directory listing in PuTTY

Tags: ssh, sftp, putty

I am using PuTTY to connect to an intermediate server and `sftp` to connect further to a production server. Once I type in `ls` command on a production server a lot of files appear and I cannot see them all because there are too many files.

I've trying using `ls | less`, but that doesn't work:

```
 sftp> ls | less
 Couldn't stat remote file: No such file or directory
 Can't ls: "/export/home/wbcm/|" not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three different solutions:

### Increasing PuTTY's scrollback

You are probably limited by PuTTY's default scrollback of 2000 lines.

Go to the *Windows* page of PuTTY configuration dialog and locate the *Lines of scrollback* box. Enter a value larger than default 2000.

[image: PuTTY lines of scrollback]

### Proper use of the `less` command

Regarding the `ls | less`. You are in the `sftp`, not in a shell. There's no `less` command in the OpenSSH `sftp` client. Let alone an output piping (the `|`). You need to apply the `less` to an output of the `sftp` command. E.g.:

```
echo "ls /home/username/zillions_of_files" | sftp username@example.com | less
```

### See files in WinSCP using tunneling

I'm assuming that you ssh (using PuTTY) to some server, where you sftp (using the OpenSSH command line client) to another (production) server, because you cannot sftp directly to the production server from your Windows machine (that being the reason you cannot connect using WinSCP). If that's the case, use the [tunneling feature of WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_tunnel) to bypass the restriction and list the files directly in WinSCP.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: yes that is the case, i don't have access to another server (production) thats why i needed to SFTP to access the production server.Oh ok I will take a look at the tunneling feature in WinSCP thank you! very helpful!